# Unique constraint on join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a user, who has a many books:

```
public class User {

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name="user_book")
    private Set<Book> books;

}
```

this will create in database a join table:

```
|user_id|book_id|
-----------------
|1      |2      |
|1      |3      |
|2      |1      |
```

Problem is that unique constraint **is only** on `book_id` column. 
That means 2 user can't have the same book.
If I would like add to `user(id:1)` a `book(id:1)`, then I got: `BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry`

Is this normal ? or this is bug?
If not a bug, how i can configure hibernate to create unique constraint on pair (`user_id`,`book_id`) not only on `book_id` in join table.

Hibernate: `3.6.4.Final`

MySQL: `5.0.21`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your association is a **One** To Many. This means that **One** user can have Many books. If you want to be able to have a book shared by several users, make it a ManyToMany association: a user would have several books, and a book would have several users.